# Create upload path based on current year and month

Tags: php, mkdir, uploading

For uploading, I want to check if the year folder and month sub-folder already exist. If they don't, I would like to create them and save my uploads there.

```
<?php
     $newname =  $_POST['changename'];
      $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if(!(
        $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']=='image/jpeg' ||
        $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']=='image/png' ||
        $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']=='image/gif' ||
        $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']=='image/bmp' 
        )) // if file does not equal these types, kill it
        {
        echo  $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'] . " is not an acceptable format.";
        die();
        }

        if ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["size"] > 20000000)
            {
                echo "File too big. Max 20mb";
                die();
            }

        if ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {
                $new_file_name = $newname.".".$extension;
                $path = "uploads/".$new_file_name;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"],$path);
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "success" => true,
                    "imagepath" => $path,
                    "filetype" => $_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"],
                    "new_file_name" => $newname,
                    "fileName" => $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"],
                    "fileTmp" => $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"],                     
                ));
            }
 ?>
```

Comment: Permission granted...Go ahead and wrie the code and come back if you are stuck with some error..

Comment: you can do it using **is_dir()** function.

Comment: you should determine which format of  year and month you want to use in ur folder system ... i mean u want to create the year directory in four digits or two

Comment: I edited my question with my current codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with something like this:

```
$year = date("Y");   
$month = date("m");   
$filename = "../".$year;   
$filename2 = "../".$year."/".$month;

if(file_exists($filename)){
    if(file_exists($filename2)==false){
        mkdir($filename2,0777);
    }
}else{
    mkdir($filename,0777);
}
```

You have to adjust this code depending on directory structure that you have. It shows you basic idea of checking whether the file or directory exists and if it's not, then it will be created you.

#### EDIT 1:

Adjusting your code to your need, it should be this (not tested):

```
$path = "uploads/";

$year_folder = $path . date("Y");
$month_folder = $year_folder . '/' . date("m");

!file_exists($year_folder) && mkdir($year_folder , 0777);
!file_exists($month_folder) && mkdir($month_folder, 0777);

$path = $month_folder . '/' . $new_file_name;
```

NOTE: Put it right above

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"],$path);
```

Comment: You just copy/paste it? If you need just working solution, I will need more than that in your question!

Comment: Can I ask what's 0777 means? what's it for?

Comment: It is a UNIX file permission, 777 means read+write+execute for owner, group and everyone. The permission number should be written in octal (with 0 prefix)

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I really don't know how mkdir works.. I edited my question with my codes. Could you please help me?

Comment: I believe this answer is fine. Maybe (if I understand correctly) there is month mkdir missing in else branch, but otherwise useful.

Comment: I used the code, I was able to create a folder for the year, but after that I got a 10.file :\

Answer (score 3):

`is_dir` should be used to check the existence of a directory/folder NOT `file_exists`, `file_exists` will also return true if a the file is found with that filename. 
There is a recursive parameter which when set to true will make all nested directories. 
e.g.

```
    $pathname_parameter = date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/';
    $mode_parameter = 0777;
    $recursive_parameter = true; 

    if (!is_dir($pathname_parameter)) {
        mkdir($pathname_parameter, $mode_parameter, $recursive_parameter);
    }
```

So yours would be something like this

```
    $new_file_name = $newname.".".$extension;
    $pathname = 'uploads/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/';

    if (!is_dir($pathname)) {
        mkdir($pathname, 0777, true);
    }
    $destination = $pathname . $new_file_name;  
    /* if( (!is_file($destination)) || (isset($_POST['overwrite']) && (int)$_POST['overwrite']) ){ */
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $destination);    
   /* } */
```

Comment: @jekeyeke thanks for the edit suggestion, i have changed my answer even though your edit was rejected.

Comment: `$pathname` should end with forward slash or it will place file in year directory

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!file_exists(date("Y")))//Checking if year folder exist
    mkdir(date("Y"));//Creating folder if it dosent exist(You may need to add ,0777) in UNIX
if (!file_exists(date("Y").'/'.date("m")))//Checking for month folder
    mkdir(date("Y").'/'.date("m"));
$path='./'.date("Y/m").'/';
```

Answer (score 0):

1st parameter path example "assets/upload" 2nd parameter allow file "option NUll" 3rd parameter file name example "image.png" return file name

```
public function upload_file_date_directory($paths,$allow = '', $file) {

   $year = date('Y');
   $month = date('m');
   $path = "./". $paths . $year . "/" . $month;
   if (!is_dir($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
   }

   $config['upload_path'] = $path;
   $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|$allow";
   $config['max_size'] = '3000';
   $config['max_width'] = '2000';
   $config['max_height'] = '2000';
   $config['file_name'] = trim(str_replace(" ", "", date('dmYHis')));
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);

   $newimg = '';
   if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file)) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $newimg = $error;
        return $newimg;
   } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $newimg = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        return  $year . "/" . $month ."/".$newimg;
   }

}
```